# Change midi channel on proMIDI library

Tags: java, processing, midi, channel

I'm using [promidi](http://creativecomputing.cc/p5libs/promidi/) on [processing](http://processing.org/) library, and I'm send midi notes from my code, but all notes be on channel 1 and i want send to others channels i not found how to make this, someone know a way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about [ProgramChange](http://creativecomputing.cc/p5libs/promidi/programchange_class_programchange.htm)?

```
midiOut.sendProgramChange(new ProgramChange(0,myNumber));
```

Comment: I not have this constructor on class ProgramChange, i have only a constructor with one param of type int. what`s version of your promidi?

Comment: Take a look at the link it has an example on how to use it.

Comment: this constructor `new ProgramChange(int,int)` is only avaliable on promidi 1, don`t have this on promidi 2 :/, i go change the library and  I'll see if it works.

Comment: thanks works, but not on promidi 2 :/ i go uses the promidi 1,I hope this put right back method.

Comment: @ademar111190 glad to know. Don't really know what are you doing but I recommend looking at PD (pure data) and/or Max/MSP